# Java program to optimize amount of money you can spend on different items to maximize value

Tags: java

So I am trying to design an algorithm to calculate the specific items I can buy, based on the amount of money I have, to get the most value of the purchase, given that each item has specific value. So my plan was to use nested if else statements etc... But that is extremely inefficient. Any input?

I am not asking for anyone to solve this for me. I am simply asking if this way is one of the least efficient but still successful way of doing it.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. If the 'value' is just the stated value (e.g. the price), then all things are equal: it doesn't matter which items you buy. If some items are actually more valuable than the price, that has to be part of the problem description.

Comment: This looks like the Knapsack Problem. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Comment: Philipp yeah I think you guys helped me greatly. this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to implement the Knapsack problem.

You can read about it here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Comment: Yeah I actually started researching Calculus optimization problem to implement is as Java code. I think the Knapsack is similar. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I dont completely understand the question but, depending on your conditions a **switch** block  could be better, but its actual performance increase is little

ref: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Comment: Yeah that's a possibility. So idea is that I want to maximize my value of money . Each item has different value and a different amount. The higher price of the item, the higher the value. I am thinking of using an actual equation or calculus to implement it but I am not sure if anyone has already done similar thing.

Comment: im still having a hard time following the question, if you create some kind of example code or maybe rephrase your question, i could pick it up.